# Update SQLite3 Library in XCode

Tags: ios, sqlite, xcode7

Is there a way to update the built-in SQLite3 library in XCode? I'm using XCode 7.3 with iOS 9.3 SDK - this comes with SQLite3 library version 3.0 as it appears in the frameworks and libraries. I need to execute a certain command but it is only supported in SQLite3 version 3.9 and later.

Comment: What happens if your app installed on an iOS device ? Will it also support that version ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it shows an error with the command since it is only supported in 3.9

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is integrate [the FMDB Cocoapod](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb):

> pod 'FMDB/standalone'   # FMDB with latest SQLite amalgamation source

That is absolutely your best option for working with SQLite conveniently in iOS. Enjoy!

Comment: And this updates the version of `sqlite3` or simply provides an alternative interface?

Comment: You'll be using the version the pod provides instead of the System version when you link with it instead of the System's dylib.